# Getting access to CheckBox as a Control in DataGridViewCheckBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can I get an access to CheckBox as a **Control** in DataGridViewCheckBoxCell?

Comment: -1. C# is a language, not a GUI framework. I don't know if this is Winforms, ASP.Net, WPF, Silverlight, or WinRT.

Comment: DataGridViewCheckBoxCell c = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)datagridview.CurrentCell;
(c as Control).... I don't have an idea

Answer (score 1):

Simply: No.
Because `DatagridviewCheckBoxColumn` is not inheriting from `Control`, but inheriting from `DataGridViewElement` which is the parent class (not inheriting from `Control` either!) .

Source: [DatagridviewCheckBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcheckboxcolumn%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)